# What is the correct positioning of "Please" in a sentence or indeed is there one?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

> - **Please** can you help me with this question?
> - Can you **please** help me with this question?
> - Can you help me with this question **please**?

Is there a correct place for *please* in this question or is it just a matter of choice?

Comment: When teaching polite language, I ask my students to insert 'please' into various sentences as many times as they can. Gets to be quite fun when they get the hang of it.

Comment: Of course, using "can" instead of "will" might open you up to smart alecs who are ignorant of the second modal form of "can" which conveys permission and not ability.

Comment: @Kevin: *Could* would be more polite than *will*, at least in British English.

Comment: In AE, can, could, will, and would can all be used pretty much interchangeably in the OP's sentence with no difference in politeness levels.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are four places to put the **please** in that sentence.

> Please, can you help me with this question?
>
> Can you please help me with this question?
>
> Can you help me, please, with this question?
>
> Can you help me with this question, please?

Note that of the four, the second is the only one that isn't usually set off by commas.

Comment: I would not use a comma for the first, which is the form I would expect to hear from a child to an adult.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a matter of choice. I would think that putting "please" at the beginning of a question would make it more polite. None of them are wrong at least.

Answer (score 1):

"Can you please help me with this question?"
is the correct sentence for written English

The other two are used informally, while speaking hastily.

Comment: What's haste got to do with it? They are perfectly normal forms, maybe a little less formal than number 2, but there's nothing "incorrect" about them.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you *please* help me with this question?

is a correct place to put *please*.

Comment: Is *a* correct place to put "please". Not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

Of all variants here I would say that "Could you please help me?" has the greater possiblilty of being (mis)understood as showing impatience or frustration. Nevertheless I wouldn't consider any of the four formulations in Robusto's post to be "wrong".