# Is it 'can you please send me the the files?' or 'please can you send me the files?'

Tags: word-order

My instinct feels the second one is more polite but I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct. Can someone answer this and explain which is the correct and polite way to frame this question?

Comment: Replace _can_ with _could_ and use the first version if you want to sound polite.

Comment: In my view, the second one is more passive aggressive, as it emphasises the 'please'. This makes it feel like a repeated question, as in "I've asked you before, so PLEASE can you..." -- this would be the same if 'please' was stressed in spoken English in the first variant. And yes, as @user405662 says, 'could' would be more polite than 'can'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct positioning of "Please" in a sentence or indeed is there one?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20868/what-is-the-correct-positioning-of-please-in-a-sentence-or-indeed-is-there-one) Also [Where do you place 'please' in a sentence to sound the most polite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155811/where-do-you-place-please-in-a-sentence-to-sound-the-most-polite)

Comment: Why do you say "the the files"?

Comment: The variant with 'please' fronted needs careful use or it can sound sing-song childish. 405's advice is sound, though you could equally place the politeness marker at the end (after a comma). For polite requests, the question mark is optional.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference where "please" is placed in a sentence. Putting "please" at the beginning of a request makes a command sound more polite, but implies a certain expectation on the behalf of the speaker that the command will be obeyed:

"Please close the door" or "Please pass the butter".

Putting "please" at the end of the request makes it sound more like a genuine request and weakens the command.

"Put your trash in the bin, please" or "No pushing, please"

In your example, it would be more polite to say, "Send me the files, please."

Using "Please send me the files" would probably sound more like a command.

Comment: Notice that OP asks about modal-hedged requests (framed as questions). But this is a duplicate, and should be closed rather than answered.